# the module "ntvinv.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DLLRegisterServer was not found

Tags: java, windows, dll, system32

I have an application which was working fine till windows 2003 server. Recently we migrated to Windows server 2012 R2 64-bit. Since we migrated to 64-bit windows, we also migrated to 64-bit JAVA.

The problem is: 
Initially we got error saying 32-bit ntvinv.dll "Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform" so we downladed the 64-bit version of ntvinv.dll from jIntegra's web sit. Now we are facing a different problem all together where we are not able to register the DLL itself. Insted we get error pop-up saying the "ntvinv" Resource DLL not found errno=[126] and the log file reads

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: D:\XXXX\lib\ext\ntvinv.dll: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed
            at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1803)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1728)
            at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
            at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1028)

When i try to register the DLL manually i get following error

the module "ntvinv.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DLLRegisterServer was not found

Make sure that "ntvinv.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again.

Can any one please help me resolve the issue?

EDIT:
I ran dependency walker on the said DLL and found following

[image]

A point to note:
We have exact same set-up on two different machine(lets say machine A and machine B). On one of the machines it works fine where as on other i get the above mentioned errors with the DLL. When i run dependency walker on both the machines i get exact same snap shot as pasted above.

Any more help in this regards will be really appreciatied. I am a new bee to the DLL world.

Edit 2:
One more observation.. I see few Visual C++ and Visual Studio runtimes on the machine where the DLL works fine and not on the machine where it does not work.. could this be the reason?

Comment: Only DLLs containing COM classes can be registered, so it's not unexpected that it failed.

Comment: have you tried using windows System File Checker ? SFC /SCANNOW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is cleanly spelled out here:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: D:\XXXX\lib\ext\ntvinv.dll
```

One or more missing DLL dependencies are missing in order to load ntvinv.dll.

Run `dumpbin.exe /imports ntvinv.dll` to find out what DLLs are implicitly linked. [Dumpbin.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c.aspx) is a tool typically installed by Visual Studio. But it probably comes bundled with the [Windows Platform SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/desktop/aa904949.aspx).

You can also use [Depends.exe](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to get similar information.

I think the [windows event viewer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-information-event-logs-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7) may also report the dependent dll in either the Application or System logs that caused the binary to fail to load. Go reproduce the error, then check the event logs.

My hunch tells me that it's a version of the MSVCRT that is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your main or in the constructor.

```
try {
      System.loadLibrary("ntvinv");
  } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The JIntegra dll (ntvinv.dll) is not in the system path .", "Warning", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
      //System.exit(0);
  }
```